# Human readable Firebase crash reporting issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I am trying to integrate Firebase Crash Reporting to my app. I want it to be reported human readable and accoding to [Firebase tutorial](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios) I have added a Run Script in XCode project. I set the data as below.

```
GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:2x25x16352xx:ios:ee9bx7ae0a1e6xx

"${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "$SRCROOT/xxx-4869xxd0b7xxx.json"
```

But when I run the app I receive an error:

```
{
  "error" : "invalid_grant",
  "error_description" : "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token and in a reasonable timeframe"
}
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

I am wondering what cause can cause that.

Some tip: When I select `Run script only when installing`, the app runs correctly.

Comment: Can you try running "rm $HOME/Library/Preferences/com.google.SymbolUpload*"?

It's possible you have a bad cached OAUTH token.

Comment: Unfortunately still returns the same error.

Comment: Another idea.  Can you use an absolute path instead of relying on the SRCROOT substitution?  It's possible the substitutions isn't working as expected.

Comment: There is no problem about finding the document. I tried that as well. The problem is something different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer of the problem after a work for 1 week. It was too simple. My computer's clock was not true. I fixed it manually and all corrected magically.